# How do you position views and other UI items in a fragment layout?

Tags: android, xml

I have a message interface consisting of a listview, an edit text box and a button found in a tutorial online. In my implementation of the xml it lays out perfectly with the listview above the text box and button. However, when I try to implement the layout using two fragments (1) for an audio player at the top of the screen and (2) below that for the messaging, I cannot force the text box and button to display below the list view.

How can I do that below are the XMLs.
(1) Works as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation ="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id ="@+id/message_list"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/new_message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="100"
            android:inputType="text">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/send_message"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

(2) Positions the text and button at the top of or near the top of the list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/message_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@null" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/new_message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="100"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:labelFor="@id/new_message" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/send_message"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Changing (2) to linear layout has not fixed my issue.

Comment: I see multiple issues with your second layout. you can't use android:orientation="vertical" in a relativelayout.

Comment: Thanks @PrisonMike. Using LinearLayout fixed my problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your second layout has no constraints. You should make sure that your LinearLayout is aligned bottom and the listview is above the LinearLayout. It should be something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/message_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/llText"
    android:divider="@null" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llText"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/new_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:labelFor="@id/new_message" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks @Pavan. I'll try your answer to see if it works although I seemed to fix it using linear layout as I'll post in my answer.

Comment: Got two messages: "Invalid layout param in a LinearLayout: layout_above." and: "Obsolete... Invalid layout param in a LinearLayout: layout_alignParentBottom.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your problem. 
You get the above error when you try to use those params in a linearlayout. But i have used it in a relative layout. Do check you if used a relative layout.
My solution seems to work in my editor, btw the relativelayout closing tag was missing in the snippet, maybe that caused the issue. I have made an edit on that. Anyway good day !

Answer (score 0):

This somehow fixed my problem although it seemed not to have worked before.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.app.MessageFragment">


    <ListView
        android:id ="@+id/message_list"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/new_message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="100"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:labelFor="@id/new_message" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/send_message"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```